# Nginx not redirecting to 404 page if the directory does not exist

Tags: php, nginx, cluster-computing, haproxy

I have a Nginx (frontend) -> HAProxy -> web1 & web2 servers (backend, Nginx, php5-fpm).
My problem is when I try to access the frontend Nginx server (domain.com/test) it returns me back to index.html page. It just won't show the 404 page if the directory 'test' does not exist.

1. This is my Nginx (frontend) config: http://pastebin.com/zTCVxuXt
2. This is my HAProxy config (on the same server as Nginx frontend):
   http://pastebin.com/vXNxDCQZ
3. This is my WEB1 config (backend): http://pastebin.com/FYYCJBP0 (same
   for WEB2).

Thanks! (and sorry for not posting configs here but it would be a mess)

**EDIT: I now deleted index.html and I get 404 in root directory but when i add /test I get error 500.**

Comment: Apparently all nginx does is proxy to HAProxy, the issue is on that level, I can't help you much with the HAProxy issue, but if you want you can tell nginx to return 404 right away wihtout going to HAProxy if the file doesn't exist, would you like that ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Thanks for answer but I already fixed it ;)